# picture "undefined" with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

im trying to get a picture uploaded using multer, here is my server side

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${file.originalname}`)
    }
})


const upload = multer({storage: storage});

app.post('/upload', upload.single("pic"), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.file)
    res.send('File uploaded!')
})
```

in my post method my req.file is undefined

this is my client side

```html
<form action="/upload" method="post">
                    <input type="file" id="files" style="visibility: hidden;" name = "pic" accept="image/*">
                    <br>
                    <label for="files" id="files" class = "lbl">Select file</label>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" id = "submit">
                </form>
```

if anyone can send a solution it would be amazing.
thanks you.

Comment: When sending files over to servers, the content type needs to be in multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `multer().single(...)` fills `req.file` only if the content type is `multipart/form-data`:

```html
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: for some reason it dosent seem to work... im still getting undefined after changing it