why can't i use multer cloudinary storage
I've tried to use CloudinaryStorage (the Multer engine) so I don't have to save the image on the server before uploading it to the cloud. However, whenever I make a request, the response says, "No file uploaded." Is this an issue with my code or the multer-storage-cloudinary package? The Cloudinary configuration is correct.
Here are the package versions:

multer: ^1.4.2
cloudinary: ^1.27.0
multer-storage-cloudinary: ^4.0.0

Here's my code:
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');

const app = express(); 

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: 'Scribe',
  api_key: 'abc',
  api_secret: 'def',
});

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary: cloudinary,
  params: {
    allowed_formats: ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'], 
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  console.log('req body after parsing:', req.body);
  console.log('req file:', req.file);
  if (!req.file) {
    return res.status(400).json("No file uploaded");
  }
  res.json({ url: req.file.path });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Running on port 3000');
});


Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71990644/picture-undefined-with-multer

Could you please post your full res?

Thanks for the help! I found out the issue was with the Postman extension in VS Code—it wasn't sending images properly. However, when I tested it from the frontend in the browser, it worked fine. I upgraded to the postman app for Windows, and now everything is working perfectly.
